# want to automate cbind in R

Tags: r, cbind

my code:

orders column one of new data frame by column two of previous data frame

```
matchOrder<- function(x,y){
    y[match(x[,2], y[,1]),];
}
```

orders column one of new data frame by column one of previous data frame

```
matchOrder1<- function(x,y){
    y[match(x[,1], y[,1]),];
}
```

creates the individual data frames as we want them and bind them

```
onea<- one[order(one[,2]),];
twoa<- matchOrder(onea,two);
threea<- matchOrder(twoa,three);
foura<- matchOrder(threea,four);
##error
fivea<- matchOrder1(foura,five);
##error
finaltable<- cbind(onea, twoa, threea, foura, fivea);
finaltable;
```

What I want to do is when foura throws an error, I want to make a function that will paste and cbind in everything before foura (or any error), this way I dont have to always modify the code before running it.

output:

```
finaltable<- cbind(onea, twoa, threea);
```

Comment: This is quite hard to follow... but aren't you merging tables here?  instead of sorting and cbinding, you can use the `merge` function to accomplish the same thing...

Comment: @ Justin when I merger one - five and an error is thrown in five lets say, wont that cause my merge function to throw and error? I want to bind or merge these dataframes up to table before the table that is causing an error.

Comment: Yeah, so you've merged 1,2,3 and 4.  Then 5 errors so you just return your current result... (the merged first four).  Also, if these are at all large, I would consider using `data.table` and its much optimized `merge`.

Comment: @ Justin, I have hundreds of dataframes, that are 250 rows in length. I know how  many I will have at the end, and currently I am adding a new one everyday. I would like to automate this step, so I dont have to always  go into my code and add another piece to the code so the new dataframe will be incorporated in the study.

Comment: use a list!  Something like `do.call(rbind, lapply(filenames, read.csv))`.